# DHCPv6 assigned 64 prefix instead of 112 prefix

Tags: 14.04, ipv6, dhcpd, dhcpv6

I'm trying to setup my DHCPv6 on ubuntu to assign an address with a 112 prefix.
My configuration looks like this:

```
subnet6 2001:db8:a0b::640a:0/112 {
      range6 2001:db8:a0b::6464:640a 2001:db8:a0b::6464:640d;
      default-lease-time 600;
      max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

I'm expecting to be assigned with IPv6 with the following notation:

```
2001:db8:a0b::6464:640a/112
```

but instead I'm getting

```
2001:db8:a0b::6464:640a/64
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't done any IPv6 configurations yet, but take a look at https://subnettingpractice.com/ipv6_subnetting.html and plug in your IP address there.  It looks as though your range might be incorrect.  From the numbers I got it looks like it should be `range6 2001:db8:a0b:0:0:0:6464:0 2001:db8:a0b:0:0:0:6464:ffff;`

Comment: @Terrance that range shouldn't be affecting the DHCP assignment of /64 or /112, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @ThomasWard If I plug in those range numbers into an IP calculator they come up as invalid.

Comment: @Terrance, `2001:db8::` is the prefix reserved for IPv6 documentation examples.  It's appropriate if the OP has modified the question with a dummy documentation address; a calculator might mark it invalid because it _is_ invalid for an actual device.

Comment: @user4556274 But why assign an incorrect IP address that has 5 digits after the : when it is clearly 4 digits in every example I have looked at?  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting

Comment: @Terrance, yes `6464a` is an invalid address segment.  I misunderstood which part of the address you were talking about.

Comment: @Terrance ah, right, that was not specific enough.  The OP needs to use a valid range, yes, such as 6460 through 6464 or such in the last set of digits.  As with user4556274 I didn't see that and was misunderstanding what you were referring to.

Comment: @ThomasWard You're correct. I mistakenly wrote 6464 instead of 640a. I fixed it, but the issue still occurs. Any insights?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yeah, I am sorry for not specifying that clear enough in my first comment, so I can see the confusion.  Forgive me my friend!

Answer (score 0):

The range is still incorrect.  Look at the second to last segment of the IP address.  In the /112 you have 640a, but in your range you have 6464.  Make the following changes.

```
subnet6 2001:db8:a0b::640a:0/112 {
      range6 2001:db8:a0b::640a:640a 2001:db8:a0b::640a:640d;
      default-lease-time 600;
      max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

From https://subnettingpractice.com/ipv6_subnetting.html

```
Compressed Address: 2001:db8:a0b::640a:0/112
Expanded Address:   2001:0db8:0a0b:0000:0000:0000:640a:0000/112
Prefix: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0000
Range:  2001:db8:a0b:0:0:0:640a:0
2001:db8:a0b:0:0:0:640a:ffff
Number of /64s: 3.552713678800501e-15
```